# Access eclipse error markers from ant taks

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

we run a bunch of custom eclipse plugins in a headless manner througt an ant build script i.e. `"%ECLIPSE%/eclipsec" -nosplash --launcher.suppressErrors -application
 org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner
 -data C:\workspace -buildfile build.xml`

In the build.xml file we use a custom ant task `eclipse.refreshLocal` [provided by the platform](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fant_eclipse_tasks.htm) to load and refresh resources within the given workspace, this works.

Now we would like to have/use another ant task to list all error and warning markers from the workspace and pipe them to a file. The use-case is to refresh our projects and let eclipse plugins check for problems and to process them further.

Is it possible out of the box? Do we have to write some custom plugins that wrap such functionality, any clues for that?

Comment: The Ant task in that link are the only ones provided by Eclipse, there is nothing to do what you want.

Comment: Maybe some other tasks from another project? Or do we need to write an own task?